# Access float in (int * float) list in OCaml

Tags: list, functional-programming, ocaml

I have a list of type `(int * float) list`.

So, as far as I understand it (I'm new to OCaml/Functional Programming)
the list is structured like this: `[(3, 1.0); (4, 2.0); (6, 0.1)]`.

Now I want to access the first element in each tuple in the list.

I'd be happy with an example solution and an explanation.

Comment: What learning material are you using?

Comment: @glennsl the internet

Comment: I would recommend you follow a proper book or tutorial. Here's a good one explaining [list access](https://courses.cs.cornell.edu/cs3110/2021sp/textbook/data/accessing_lists.html) and [tuples](https://courses.cs.cornell.edu/cs3110/2021sp/textbook/data/tuples.html). Put the two together and you have your answer.

Comment: @glennsl thank you I will check it out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*The suggestion from @glennsl in the comments about learning resources is spot on.*

If you want an example of getting a list comprised of the first element in each tuple:

```
List.map (fun (i, _) -> i) [(3, 1.0); (4, 2.0); (6, 0.1)]
```

`List.map` applies a function to each element in a list and builds a list of the resulting values. It's a simple concept and easy enough to implement in a few lines.

```
let rec my_map f lst =
  match lst with
  | [] -> []
  | first::rest -> f first :: my_map f rest
```

Or more tersely using `function`:

```
let rec my_map f =
  function
  | [] -> []
  | first::rest -> f first :: my_map f rest
```

If we evaluated `my_map (fun (i, _) -> i) [(3, 1.0); (4, 2.0); (6, 0.1)]` it would work out something like:

```
my_map (fun (i, _) -> i) [(3, 1.0); (4, 2.0); (6, 0.1)]
3 :: my_map (fun (i, _) -> i) [(4, 2.0); (6, 0.1)]
3 :: 4 :: my_map (fun (i, _) -> i) [(6, 0.1)]
3 :: 4 :: 6 :: my_map (fun (i, _) -> i) []
3 :: 4 :: 6 :: []
[3; 4; 6]
```

The anonymous function `fun (i, _) -> i` is one which takes a tuple of two items and returns the first. The second is unimportant to us, so we use `_` rather than giving it a name.

Note that this function is already defined in the standard library.

```
# Stdlib.fst;;
- : 'a * 'b -> 'a = <fun>
```